# Base map with no labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, basemap

I am struggling to find or import a base map without street labels in QGIS. I am using QuickMapServices Plugin and also looked for maps that I can add using XYZ Tiles.

Comment: what have you tried so far? where are you getting your base layers from?

Comment: I am using QuickMapServices Plugin and also looked for maps that I can add using XYZ Tiles

Answer (score 20):

Indeed it is a challenge to find free basemaps without labels.

I can provide this list of no-label basemaps:

- Carto Dark No Labels:

  [https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png](https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_nolabels/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D@2x.png)
- Carto Light No Labels:

  [https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png](https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D@2x.png)
- Carto Voyager No Labels:

  [https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png](https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_nolabels/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D@2x.png)
- Carto Voyager Only Labels Under:

  [https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_labels_under/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png](https://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_labels_under/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D@2x.png)
- OSM No Labels:

  [https://tiles.wmflabs.org/osm-no-labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://tiles.wmflabs.org/osm-no-labels/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)

Dont forget to take a look at their terms of use: [here](https://foundation.wikimedia.org/wiki/Maps_Terms_of_Use) and [here](https://carto.com/legal/).

---

Create a new [XYZ-Connection](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#using-xyz-tile-services) in the [browser panel](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/browser.html) and add them there.

[image]

You can find a more detailed description about how to add them at: https://geogeek.xyz/how-to-add-google-maps-layers-in-qgis-3.html

Comment: Thanks for quick help. All of the maps listed above are working fine using TMS (Tile Map Service) under the default settings, except for Carto Light. Could you please help.

Comment: I just added the URL again, it's working fine. Thanks again for great help. I spent a lot of time in the past to figure it out. :)

Comment: The OSM No Labels basemap is not working anymore, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

The QuickMapServices plugin actually has a few base layers without labels.

- **Stamen**

  - Toner Background
  - Terrain Background
- **CartoDB**

  - Dark Matter [no labels]
  - Dark Matter [no labels] (retina)
  - Positron [no labels]
  - Positron [no labels] (retina)

You might need to install the "contributed pack" to get access to the maps listed above. Note that this setting will also enable some maps that don't actually work.

[image]

While this is a rather short list, you can actually get quite a wide variety by adjusting the Color Rendering Settings of the base layers listed here. I *strongly* recommend writing down what settings you use when you make a map, otherwise it will take a very long time to re-create by trial and error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! Positron (No Label) is actually the same as Carto Light.