# Disable labeling of OSM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, labeling

Is there a way to disable the labeling of OSM in QGIS ?

If I try to create a map the labels interfere sometimes with my lines I like to depict.

[image]

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/334057/107424

Answer (score 8):

Since OSM Map data is rendered with labels, there is no way to disable them in QGIS. You need to find other sources.

If you have [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) Plugin installed, you can use `Search QMS` to search for `no labels` and you will have some results which you can try:

I found that `Voyager [no labels] (retina)` is based on OpenStreetMap data and it is rendered without labels.

[image]

Here is the same location with a standard OSM:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In your case, I would recommend you try using some variant of Vector Tile services for the base map.

Excellent candidate for free OpenStreetMap (OSM) data delivered through vector tiles is the ESRI OSM vector tile layer. The tile server is here:
`https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/z/y/x.pbf`

You can add this tile server to QGIS by

1. opening the Browser panel
2. right-clicking the new **Vector Tiles** category and choosing **New ARCGIS vector tile service connection**
3. Filling it out like this:
   [image]
   *Notice that the Service URL ends with “VectorTileServer”. There’s no “tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf”. QGIS will append that automatically before making a tile request.*

Add this layer to your map canvas and open the Styling Panel.
If you move to the labelling tab in the style panel, you see this:
[image]

***So, you have extensive control over the labelling***.
You can turn off or delete labels for all or part of the layers.

You can find additional very useful details in the excellent Morgan Hite publication: [«QGIS 3 and Vector map tiles»](https://wanderingcartographer.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/qgis-3-and-vector-map-tiles).

Of course, in addition to Vector Tiles from ESRI, there are excellent free services with beautiful ready styles from Mapbox, MapTiler and other companies.

Comment: Can such a connection be configured to get the place labels in a preferred language?

Answer (score 3):

OpenStreetMaps provide a free tiling service, which is good for most quick visualisation/background reference purposes.
If you need more specific data representation, I would suggest to install your own tile server, which you can the configure to math your exact rendering needs.
It is actually easier than you might think, for eaxample Switch2OSM has a pre-packaged docker option which takes seconds to install:

[image]

https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/

Then you would just need to customize the way mapnik (the "renderer" of the Switch2OSM bundle) styles the tiles via editing the `mapnik.xml` file referenced in `Dockerfile`.

https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/XMLConfigReference

Comment: Well, you can't really influence how the tiles will look like. Leaflet is not really a renderer. Leaflet just serves pre-rendered tiles. So if you don't like the style of the tiles then you need to configure a different tile server.

Comment: You are right, thanks! Edited with reference to mapnik.