Free tile layer without roads or labels
Is there a free tile layer without roads and labels ?
I'm trying to create interactive history maps and current city names and roads are irrelevant. I'm looking for a tile layer that only displays seas and rivers (even without mountains).
I could not find such a simple map on Leaflet providers.
Natural Earth Data provides interesting data but I'd like to avoid building the tile server.

If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

related https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/334063/276

Are vector tile are fine for you ? if yes have a look at https://openmaptiles.org/about/  (or find any other source of free vector tile). With vector tile you will be able to create a style to display only what you want the way you want
